# Texture stretched along the edge?

Tags: texturing, uv

I was making a simple sofa. I checked 'remove doubles', 'adjusting scale' or 'recalculate'. As a beginner so far those were all I could check :S The problem is along the edge texture is stretched. I've been searching for how to fix it for days but couldn't get through. I also tried to add more loops in the model and start again and again. But I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thank you for your help!

[image: It's a leather texture. In the picture you can see where it's stretched]

[image]

Comment: Removing doubles modified your geometry, and hence the texture mapping. You need to re-unwrap your model, or manually fix that part of the UV layout

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why Smart UV unwrap doesn't solve the problem. I did like you said marking seams and then unwrapped and it worked :D